# spongy castle asn1 vulnerability

Tags: android, openssl

OpenSSL versions before April 2012 had a vulnerability known as ASN1 BIO vulnerability (http://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20120419.txt).
I am now using Spongy Castle on Android to solve our security needs, and I am wondering if Spongy Castle is (or was) vulnerable to this as well.

I did a Google search on the subject, but cannot find anything about it.

Does anyone here know whether this affects Spongy Castle at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bouncy Castle and, by extension, Spongy Castle do not use any OpenSSL code for ASN.1 parsing. All code is developed in Java, and AFAIK does not borrow from OpenSSL. So, in theory, it should not have the same vulnerability. Especially since it is related to OpenSSL-specific API's (BIO's).